# Can I split two slivers that using the same data?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have `SliverMasonryGrid` list (from package [flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view)) which I want to split with `SliverToBoxAdapter` and list same items with `SliverMasonryGrid` again.

Here is what it looks in code:

```
Expanded(
  child: CustomScrollView(
    controller: widget.scrollController,
    physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(
        parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
    shrinkWrap: true,
    slivers: [
      SliverPadding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: size.width * 0.03)
        sliver: SliverMasonryGrid.count(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            mainAxisSpacing: size.width * 0.03,
            crossAxisSpacing: size.width * 0.03,
            childCount: 2,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Item(
                content: widget.dataList[index].content
              );
            }
        ),
      ),
      SliverToBoxAdapter(
        child: Container(...),
      ),
      SliverPadding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: size.width * 0.03)
        sliver: SliverMasonryGrid.count(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            mainAxisSpacing: size.width * 0.03,
            crossAxisSpacing: size.width * 0.03,
            childCount: widget.dataList.length - 2,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Item(
                content: widget.dataList[index + 2].content
              );
            }
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

The problem is when I scroll through this, when I reach indexes 6 and 7 of second `SliverMasonryGrid` list is coming back to beginning, to index 0 of first `SliverMasonryGrid`. I actually don't know how to handle with this, is it actually possible to do what I want?

Comment: you found the insect (bug) in `SliverMasonryGrid` - if you use "normal"  `SliverGrid.count` instead, it works fine

Comment: @pskink but ```SliverGrid.count``` doesn't have ```childCount``` and ```itemBuilder```

Comment: i meant [SliverGrid.builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverGrid/SliverGrid.builder.html)

Comment: and which GridDelegate I should use in it?

Comment: `SGDWFCAC` will work

Comment: Sorry for still bothering you, but in ```SGDWFCAC``` as in ```SGDWMCAE``` it's parameter for ```childAspectRatio```, I want to have my items dynamic height, as it looks in masonry grid design, how to deal with it?

Comment: and if you still want to use `SMG` then fill the bug report with the minimal not working code and ..... wait till the bug is fixed

Comment: hehehe, seems someone did it already (3 weeks ago): https://github.com/letsar/flutter_staggered_grid_view/issues/335 but I would fill another bug report with the code...

Comment: btw instead of that first `SMG` why don't you add your first two items inside `SliverToBoxAdapter`? so its child is `Column[Row[item0, item1], Container]`

Comment: Two is just for example. It will be dynamic

Comment: too bad, luckily the author of `SMG` answered quickly, so ....